# "No Procfile detected" in Sinatra app heroku push

Tags: heroku, sinatra, procfile

I am new with Sinatra and heroku. I am trying to push a small Sinatra app to heroku and I am getting this error,

```
 Bundle completed (24.34s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> WARNINGS:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       ##I have gone over the docs a few times and added unicorn 
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web

-----> Compressing... done, 17.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v8
```

This is what my gem file looks like

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   ruby '2.1.1'
   gem 'sinatra'
   gem 'sinatra-contrib'
   gem 'typhoeus'
   gem 'pry'
   gem 'rspec'
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'unicorn'
   gem 'thin', '1.2.7'
```

I have tried  many things that I have seen online and This error still appears. Sorry if this is a silly question But its driving me nuts! If you would like to see anymore files in the app I will happily add them, I am just not to sure what ones to add..

Thank you for your time and I appreciate your help.

Comment: please use first google before you asking, heruku has a nice doc https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Procfile` tells Heroku about different process types (commands) your application can run. For Ruby apps, Heroku expects you to declare at least one `web` process type, and also automatically initiates two additional processes by default: `rake` and `console`.

This means that your Ruby app should be able to run a web process (this is the process that actually serves web pages and assets), run `rake` tasks, and provide you with a shell-like console (access it by running `heroku run console` in top-level of your app).

All you need to do is add a blank text file called `Procfile` to the top level folder of your app, with just one line of code (if you're using Rack):

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

Or if you're using pure Sinatra (without Rack):

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT
```

You should really read [Define a Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#define-a-procfile) and [The Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) in Heroku's dev center to clear up any confusion.